# PPA package build fails but I can't figure out why?

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to upload a build to my PPA but everytime the build fails with the same error:

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/184824533/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-i386.konzolno-radio_1.0.3-0ubuntu1_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

I can't understand where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your application is trying to install during the build/compile process.  For Debian/Ubuntu packages, the idea is that the package builds and contains the binaries and rules for where to install them.  There are `debian/PACKAGENAME.install` files which you use to define where executables are installed.  That is of course assuming you have the binaries compiled and ready to move into their correct locations on disk when the package is installed.

Look towards the end of that file here:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/build/buildd/konzolno-radio-1.0.3'
installing executable file to /usr/local/bin
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/konzolno-radio': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/build/buildd/konzolno-radio-1.0.3'
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/build/buildd/konzolno-radio-1.0.3'
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: /usr/bin/fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

The problem you have is your package is trying to actually install the file to `/usr/local/bin` during compile.  That's what you're doing wrong, change your compiler rules to NOT install automatically.  You have to let `dpkg` do the installation of what goes where.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to change debian/rules to not install package.Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Cyberpower I'm not a full on developer, but I'd need to look at the rules file, maybe if you provided the text I could, but I have too much other stuff on my schedule to deal with helping fix a `debian/rules` file right now...

Comment: Here is my debian/rules file : http://pastebin.com/brFThm5H .I understand you,take look if you have time enough,i will continue reading on the net about the problem.

Comment: @Cyberpower i think you're asking a different question than your original question is asking now.  This one is "Why is the PPA build failing?"  Your current question is now "How do I set up the `debian/rules` file to NOT try and install the binaries during build time?"  Note that not every set of code is capable of doing that.